# Resource controller destroy method not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a button on my CRUD application that looks like this:

```php
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="{{route('topic.destroy', $topic->id)}}">
```

When the user clicks the button it loads the `show` method in my resource controller and not the `destroy` method.

My routes:

```php
Route::resource('/main_topic', 'MainTopicController');
Route::resource('/topic', 'TopicController');
Route::resource('/post', 'PostController');
```

Why is it not using the correct controller method?

Comment: Show your routes file...

Comment: i have heard that you need to make an forum but is that realy required seems like something that shouldn't be needed becouse you can of course add an custom route for it to

Comment: @JeremyHarris added them

Comment: Do `php artisan routes:list` on the command line, and you can see all of the routes and the methods needed for each route. A `href` link is GET only.

Comment: @aynber i know about the php artisan routes:list didn't know it was GET only thansk for that extra information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any HTTP action pointing to POST, PUT, or DELETE routes that are defined in the web routes file should include a CSRF token field. Otherwise, the request will be rejected. You can read more about CSRF protection in the CSRF [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('topic.destroy', $topic->id)}}">
    @csrf
    @method('Delete')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</button>
</form>
```